# MySQL after update trigger with number of affected rows condition

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update

In MySQL, I want to create a trigger with `AFTER UPDATE` triggering event for my `user` table.

In next, I have a table named `user_log` which is use to store the modifications that occurred on the parent table `user` after any update commands.

So, data in `user_log` table need be as follows:

```
select * from user_log;
+--------+---------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------------------+------+
| log_id | user_id | action                     | old_data      | new_data       | changed_date        | read |
+--------+---------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------------------+------+
|      1 |      10 | Changed yyy's name         | yyy           | xxx            | 2022-06-20 14:06:56 | no   |
|      2 |      10 | Changed xxx's address      | No.111,       | No.112,        | 2022-06-20 19:07:38 | no   |
|      3 |      10 | Changed xxx's city         | Old City Name | New City Name  | 2022-06-20 19:07:38 | no   |
|      4 |      10 | Changed xxx's phone number | 011-5000000   | 011-4000000    | 2022-06-20 19:07:38 | no   |
+--------+---------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------------------+------+
```

As you can see from the data in the table above, it will update several columns at once. So I created my triger as follows, and its working for me.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `user_log` ;
$$
CREATE TRIGGER `user_log`
  AFTER UPDATE ON `user` 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  IF OLD.name <> NEW.name THEN
    INSERT INTO user_log (user_id,action,old_data,new_data)
    VALUES(
      NEW.user_id
    , CASE
        WHEN (NEW.name <> OLD.name)
          THEN CONCAT('Changed ', OLD.name, "'s ", 'name')
          ELSE ''
        END 
    , CASE WHEN (NEW.name <> OLD.name) THEN OLD.name ELSE '' END 
    , CASE WHEN (NEW.name <> OLD.name) THEN NEW.name ELSE '' END  
    );
  END IF;

  IF OLD.address <> NEW.address THEN
    INSERT INTO user_log (user_id,action,old_data,new_data)
    VALUES(
      NEW.user_id
    , CASE
        WHEN (NEW.address <> OLD.address)
          THEN CONCAT('Changed ', OLD.name, "'s ", 'address')    
          ELSE ''
        END 
    , CASE WHEN (NEW.address <> OLD.address) THEN OLD.address ELSE '' END 
    , CASE WHEN (NEW.address <> OLD.address) THEN NEW.address ELSE '' END  
    );
  END IF;

  IF OLD.city <> NEW.city THEN
    INSERT INTO user_log (user_id,action,old_data,new_data)
    VALUES(
      NEW.user_id
    , CASE
        WHEN (NEW.city <> OLD.city)
          THEN CONCAT('Changed ', OLD.name, "'s ", 'city')   
          ELSE ''
        END 
    , CASE WHEN (NEW.city <> OLD.city) THEN OLD.city ELSE '' END 
    , CASE WHEN (NEW.city <> OLD.city) THEN NEW.city ELSE '' END  
    );
  END IF;

  IF OLD.phone <> NEW.phone THEN
    INSERT INTO user_log (user_id,action,old_data,new_data)
    VALUES(
      NEW.user_id
    , CASE
        WHEN (NEW.phone <> OLD.phone)
          THEN CONCAT('Changed ', OLD.name, "'s ", 'phone number')    
          ELSE ''
        END 
    , CASE WHEN (NEW.phone <> OLD.phone) THEN OLD.phone ELSE '' END 
    , CASE WHEN (NEW.phone <> OLD.phone) THEN NEW.phone ELSE '' END  
    );
  END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My problem is, I have a lot more columns in the user table. Like I said, all columns or several of them are updated at once.

In that case I have to add a large amount of INSERT query to my trigger. So here I would like to know if there is another suitable way to do this.

I also tried it in this way. But its working only for one column.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `user_log`; 
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS `user_log`
  AFTER UPDATE ON user
  FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO user_log (user_id,action,old_data,new_data)
  VALUES (
  NEW.user_id
  , CASE
      WHEN (NEW.name <> OLD.name)
        THEN CONCAT('Changed ', OLD.name, "'s ", 'name')
      WHEN (NEW.address <> OLD.address)
        THEN CONCAT('Changed ', OLD.name, "'s ", 'address')    
      WHEN (NEW.city <> OLD.city)
        THEN CONCAT('Changed ', OLD.name, "'s ", 'city')   
      WHEN (NEW.phone <> OLD.phone)
        THEN CONCAT('Changed ', OLD.name, "'s ", 'phone number')    
      ELSE ''
    END
  , CASE
      WHEN (NEW.name <> OLD.name)
        THEN OLD.name
      WHEN (NEW.address <> OLD.address)
        THEN OLD.address
      WHEN (NEW.city <> OLD.city)
        THEN OLD.city
      WHEN (NEW.phone <> OLD.phone)
        THEN OLD.phone 
      ELSE ''
    END 

  , CASE
      WHEN (NEW.name <> OLD.name)
        THEN NEW.name
      WHEN (NEW.address <> OLD.address)
        THEN NEW.address
      WHEN (NEW.city <> OLD.city)
        THEN NEW.city
      WHEN (NEW.phone <> OLD.phone)
        THEN NEW.phone 
      ELSE ''
    END     
  );
```

Thank you.

Comment: You may use a JSON if you are familial.

Comment: *As you can see from the data in the table above, it will update several columns at once.* I do NOT see. Maybe, you mean "insert" and not "update"?

Comment: Your code is extremely excess. What is the reason to use `CASE` with the condition which was already checked in external `IF`? or do you not trust this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER ...
...
BEGIN
INSERT INTO user_log (user_id,action,old_data,new_data)
SELECT NEW.user_id,
       CONCAT('Changed ', OLD.name, "'s ", columnname),
       oldvalue,
       newvalue
FROM ( SELECT 'name' columnname, OLD.name oldvalue, NEW.name newvalue
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'address', OLD.address, NEW.address
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'city', OLD.city, NEW.city
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'phone', OLD.phone, NEW.phone
     ) data
WHERE NOT oldvalue <=> newvalue;       
END;
```

Also you may use ROW() constructor instead of SELECT .. UNION ALL.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=c63b122abedf9481d72129bee0d2d87d

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your answer. I tried the pattern as you provide, then I can get an error like `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list' in .........`

Comment: @ugsgknt Reproduce this problem on some online fiddle (on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 for example).

Comment: Ok sir, give me a some time I will create a fiddle for your refference...

Comment: Sir, here you can find the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=8826fd4326d4db8db7835344cc6b8e66) with sample data.

Comment: @ugsgknt This fiddle executes each code block as a batch, you do not need to set new DELIMITER in it. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=c63b122abedf9481d72129bee0d2d87d PS. Pay attention - the trigger text is fixed. Added NOT (changes must be logged), removed COALESCE (the column is NOT NULL).

Comment: Thank you, yes your fiddle seems to be working. Can you gues why I can get above error when I run this with my original table.?

Comment: Now, I cannot, I have no enough information. Complete tables definitions (for both user and user_log tables), complete trigger creation code and complete error message text needed. At least. You may create a fiddle with this info and provide a link.

Comment: Akina, Hello Sir, I have one more thing to clarify with you. When changing user password I don't need to insert old and new passwords into `user_log` table. Instead of inserting actual data, I need to insert some custom string into table like `n/a`. Sir can you tell how it is possible in my updated trigger. I tried it in this way, but it doesnt work for me..  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=559b7850390e79d828527957e9ea1a78)

Comment: @ugsgknt https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=46a921577abadd1b7518ae951d883b63

Comment: Thank you sir.. Its what I needed. Sir If you have a time its good if you can show me an example of using `ROW()` for my `UNION ALL` queries. Thanks again.